# Maintain java variable between ajax requests

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a web crawler in which I am storing the all the internal links found on the page in ArrayList (urlList)

There is a recursion method (processPage) which works on the next link of urlList and appends more links at the end.

```
for(int i = 1; i < urlList.size(); i++){
        processPage(urlList.get(i), urlList);
}
```

Now I want to return the intermittent result found back to the page through ajax call, and I will make multiple ajax call to work on the next link

```
processPage/1
processPage/2
```

How can I maintain the data of urlList between multiple ajax request. and also multiple users should be able to work on the app simultanoesly

Comment: Please enhance your question according to [this useful guide](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) in order to enable us to help you.

Comment: You, probably, should read about web sessions and what they are good for. Then, you can either store something in a session attribute, or use the session number as the key in a collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your urlList static and then will live between multiple request

Comment: Wont the urlList be common for multiple request from different users then>?

Comment: Yes ineed, I though that was not a problem, in that case maybe a static map with user/urList key/value???. If not you can always send and back to the client